# SVN server with programatic authentication

Tags: java, linux, apache, svn

I'm setting up an svn server on an amazon ec2 box and would like to handle server-side authentication dynamically on connection. Is there a way to use custom applications written in java, python, or perhaps even a simple shell script to validate authentication programmatically? An ideal solution would be one that allows me to pass a provided user/pass to a java app and return the authentication decision to svn, which then responds to the client.

I can't seem to find much on this. While I'm experienced with client-side svn, I'm new to its more advanced server capabilities and need some direction :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use apache to serve your SVN repository, the authentication and authorization is done by Apache. That means you can use most auth/z Apache modules to protect your SVN repository - internal modules as well as 3rd party modules.

There are a lot of 3rd party modules, and most likely there is one that perfectly meets your requirements. However, I recommend starting with a simple one. For example *mod-auth-external* can be used to authenticate with an external process. See the project page for more information:

- http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for. For right now, I've decided to go with mod-auth-external too.